# Merge & Find SUM of two associative array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays with time and total booking for that particular time.i need to merge this 2 arrays by adding booking count for corresponding timing.

Array 1:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 03:00 PM - 04:30 PM
        [booked] => 3
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 05:00 PM - 06:30 PM
        [booked] => 2
    )
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array
(  
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 03:00 PM - 04:30 PM
        [booked] => 3
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 07:00 PM - 08:30 PM
        [booked] => 1
    )
)
```

This is the output i need to generate..tried many ways to merge with finding sum but i can only merge this arrays...

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 03:00 PM - 04:30 PM
        [booked] => 6
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 05:00 PM - 06:30 PM
        [booked] => 2
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [time] => 07:00 PM - 08:30 PM
        [booked] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you at least have an attempt to show us …?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge` with `foreach` and `array_key_exists`

```
$a3 = array_merge($a1,$a2);
$r = [];
foreach($a3 as $v){
  array_key_exists($v->time, $r)
  ?
  ($r[$v->time]->booked += $v->booked)
  :
  ($r[$v->time] = $v);
}
print_r(array_values($r)); // re-arrange the array keys
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/JAZ4d